# How to use an external layer with the Serverless Framework?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I would like to use an external layer `arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:347034527139:layer:tf_keras_pillow:1` in my Serverless project.

I do so by having the following in my `serverless.yml`:

```
functions:
  api:
    handler: functions/api/handler.run
    layers: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:347034527139:layer:tf_keras_pillow:1
    events:
      - http:
          path: /image/{id}/{mode}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                id: true
                mode: true
```

However, when checking the AWS Lambda function in the console, there is no layer added after deployment. Any ideas?

The only way to add the layer is by manually doing so in the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layers value is an array, per the documentation: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/layers#using-your-layers.

```
functions:
  api:
    handler: functions/api/handler.run
    layers: 
      - arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:347034527139:layer:tf_keras_pillow:1
    events:
      - http:
          path: /image/{id}/{mode}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                id: true
                mode: true
```

Should work.